# How to turn off write protection in win 7 using diskpart?

Tags: windows-7, diskpart, write-protect, undo

a while back i wanted to make my USB write-protected.
So as suggested somewhere i used the **CMD** command 
`attributes disk set readonly`
Now i want to revert back to full permissions. How to achieve this?

Comment: @DavidPostill - It appears that I have provided the link to the wrong question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use

---

`attributes disk clear readonly`

---

The clear option (as opposed to `set`) removes an attribute. 
Here is the syntax diagram:

---

`attributes disk [{set | clear}] [readonly] [noerr]`

---

Documentation here: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg252649(v=ws.11).aspx